# A problem on Möbius function

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, complex-numbers

Here is an exercise from the text book "Combinatorics" (J.H.van Lint, R.M. Wilson)

Let $f_n(z)$ be the function that has all its zeros as all the numbers $\alpha$ for which $\alpha^n=1$ but $\alpha^k\ne1$ for $1\leq k\leq n$. Prove that
$$f_n(z)=\prod\limits_{k|n}(z^k-1)^{\mu (n/k)}.$$

Comment: Do you know what the numbers $a$ are? Do you see what $\prod_{d\mid n}f_d(z)$ is?

Comment: Yes I know $\alpha$ is the $n$ th root of unity but i couldn't see that product of $f_d(z)$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

denote $\alpha$ the primitive root of nth unit, then the n roots are $\alpha^i$, $i=1\dots n$ and $\alpha^n=1$. denote $(x,y)=gcd(x,y)$.

so

$$z^n-1=\prod_{i=1}^{n}(z-\alpha^i)$$

then we focus on what $f_n(z)$ is like, the root of $f_n(z)$ is something like $\alpha^i$, then we find out what $i$ is in $f_n(z)$

if $(i,n)=d>1$, that is to say we have a root $\alpha^i$ in $f_n(z)$, then

$$
(\alpha^i)^{\frac{n}{d}}=(\alpha^{\frac{i}{d}})^n=1
$$

but $n/d<n$, which violate the defination of $f_n(z)$

so

$$
f_n(z)=\prod_{(i,n)=1}(z-\alpha^i)
$$

then we take a deep look at $z^n-1$

$$
z^n-1=\prod_{i=1}^{n}(z-\alpha^i)=\prod_{d|n}\prod_{(i,n)=d}(z-\alpha^i)=\prod_{d|n}\prod_{(i/d,n/d)=1}(z-(\alpha^d)^{i/d})=\prod_{d|n}f_{n/d}(z)=\prod_{d|n}f_d(z)
$$

then we can use Möbius inversion formula, and get

$$
f_n(z)=\prod\limits_{d|n}(z^d-1)^{\mu (n/d)}
$$

Comment: happy it helps!

Comment: The point here is to observe that all roots of 
${f_n}\left( z \right)$ are ${\alpha ^i}$ where $\alpha $ is the primitive root of n^th root and 
$\left( {i,n} \right) = 1$. So, for each 
$d$ dividing $n$, the roots of ${f_d}\left( z \right)$ form partition of the set 
$\left\{ {1,2, \ldots ,n} \right\}$.